# how to filter all columns of html table using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I am creating custom data table. I have added sorting, pagination but unable to do searching on all columns. Here is the URL of what i have created

https://codesandbox.io/s/yv48o7onwj

Data array contains uppercase words and integers.

How to implement filter/search on all columns using single input box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const filtered = products.filter(item => (
   item.id === searchString ||
   item.name === searchString ||
   item.price === searchString ||
   item.qa === searchString ||
   item.qr === searchString ||
   item.vendor === searchString
));
```

and then replace `{products.map(item => {` on line 326 to `{filtered.map(item => {`

Comment: I am trying this

Comment: Thanks for idea, its worked. Only change i did was instead of this item.name === searchString, i used item.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())

Comment: No worries! Glad that it helps! Alternatively, you can also use `String.prototype.startsWith()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith for the name search.